# Define variables in loops using loop indicies

Tags: matlab

I would like to use a 'for loop' to process a dataset, where the output names would be be determined by the index. Is this possible?

Here is what I tried:

```
for i=1:5
[sortedX,sortingIndices] = sort(dataname,'descend');
outputarray(i)={sortedX,sortingIndices}
end
```

Comment: If you're wanting dynamic variable names, it's best to use either a cell array or `struct` with dynamic field names to hold your data

Comment: I did not see the original question.